# What are some good graduate-level econometrics books for someone with a strong mathematics background?

Tags: econometrics, reference-request

Related: [Book recommendations on empirical methods in economic research and econometrics?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/110/book-recommendations-on-empirical-methods-in-economic-research-and-econometrics)

I would like to focus mainly on *graduate texts in Econometrics*. From the question above, I gather that Wooldridge's text is nice.

In terms of "strong math background," I did my undergrad in Statistics, consisting of two semesters each of linear algebra, real analysis, and abstract algebra, along with a measure-theoretic probability course.

What are some econometrics texts that you would recommend for me? I learned some intro econometrics in a course which taught from Studenmund but was extremely bored.

Comment: Are there particular areas that interest you, like causal inference, structural, time-series?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov: I don't claim to know a ton about econometrics, but I definitely would be interested in casual inference and time-series.

Comment: Can we again have one main reference per answer? That way people could vote single books. Was a suggestion in the other question and I feel it worked great.

Comment: An excellent treatment (published 1991) you may want to look into http://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674175440. I would also second: https://www.amazon.com/Primer-Econometric-Theory-MIT-Press/dp/0262034905/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Adult" Wooldridge is great intro to various microeconometrics topics.

For time series, Hamilton's Time Series and Lutkepohl's Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis are both nice, though Hamilton is a bit dated and Lutkepohl is more focused.

As far as more foundational, rigorous material, Herman Bierens has a short Introduction to the Mathematical and Statistical Foundations of Econometrics. Gourieroux and Monfort have a whole flock of graduate econometrics texts, but to quote an anonymous reviewer, they are "in the French tradition of excellent precision and terrible pedagogics," though they have their champions.

Comment: The Wooldridge book that @Dimitriy is talking about is "Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data." "Baby" Wooldridge is "Introductory Econometrics: A Modern Approach."

Comment: (+1) for also relaying the comment on Gourieroux and Monfort.

Comment: Thank you for telling me about Wooldridge. I have really enjoyed the text and it is right up my alley. :)

Answer (score 9):

I repeat part of [my answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/110/book-recommendations-on-empirical-methods-in-economic-research-and-econometrics/116#116) in the question the OP already mentioned with some additional proposals:

Since you have a background in Statistics
["Probability Theory and Statistical Inference: Econometric Modeling with Observational Data"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521424089) 1999, by A. Spanos, provides the statistical foundations of econometrics in a way no other book does.

["Econometrics" by Hayasi](http://fhayashi.fc2web.com/hayashi_econometrics.htm), because, except of presenting a new synthesis focused around Extremum Estimators (i.e. Maximum Likelihood and Generalized Method of Moments), and of giving space to Time Series, Unit root econometrics and Co-integration, it has theoretical depth alongside very practical applications, a combination which is not usually found.

For Time-series, I don't believe you can ignore

[Hamilton's Time Series Analysis"](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/5386.html),

or

"[Lutkepohl's "Introduction to Multiple Time Series"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540262393) which has gone into its 2nd ed. as "New Introduction to Multiple Time Series" (my experience is from the first edition).

Comment: A book's "theoretical depth" is questionable when "measurability" appears exactly once in the book and is in quotes.

Comment: @Michael And since when the concept of "measurability" and related, became the standard to measure theoretical depth?

Answer (score 3):

Can't forget ["Econometric Analysis" by William Greene](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131395386). It's in its [7th edition](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~wgreene/Text/econometricanalysis.htm). It seems to get referenced lot. It sometimes skips over some detail but it does cover a broad range of topics. (Though I do like the pedagogical approach of something like Hayashi better, I think Greene might cover more ground.)

Answer (score 2):

I am tempted to deviate from other answers and suggest that the best Econometrics textbook for someone with a strong enough mathematical background might *not* be a "mathematically-minded" econometrics textbook, but rather a textbook that focuses on "empirical methods and economics research", the best of which at the moment seems to remain:

> Mostly Harmless Econometrics (https://www.mostlyharmlesseconometrics.com/)

Since you already have a strong mathematical background --- and unless you're specifically interested in the mathematical aspects of econometrics --- you are likely to learn much more (and find much more inspiration) from a book that starts and ends with a strong focus on causal inference and research design.

(This being said, by all means, do consult other answers in particular if you want to feed your interest in time-series analysis which is not covered much --- if at all --- in Mostly Harmless)